# Play html form to submit a GET request with parameter

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a play GET route, how can I use it in scala html form?

routes

```
GET  /service/register  controllers.WebRegister.register(plan?="")
```

scala html

```
@form(action = routes.WebRegister.register, 'style -> "width: 320px;") {
       <fieldset>
           <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="FREE" id="plan">
       </fieldset>
       <div class="form-actions plan-form peer-btn-center peer-m-v-t">
            <input type="submit" data-icon='&#xe6660;' class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Sign Up">
       </div>
}
```

It gives me an error:

> missing arguments for method register in class ReverseWebRegister;
>   [error] follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a
>   partially applied function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to pass it twice (via route argument and form's hidden field) so you have two solutions: use only route arg:

### Route's argument

route

```
GET  /service/register  controllers.WebRegister.register(plan: String?="")
```

template

```
@form(action = routes.WebRegister.register("free")) {
   <input type="submit">
}
```

of course if you have only this one field you can use link directly:

```
<a href='@routes.WebRegister.register("free")'>Register free</a>
```

java action

```
public static Result register(String plan) {
    return ok(plan);
}
```

### Form field only

remove argument from the route and bind field from request in controller:

route

```
GET  /service/register  controllers.WebRegister.register
```

template

```
@form(action = routes.WebRegister.register) {
   <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="free">
   <input type="submit">
}
```

java action

```
public static Result register() {
    return ok(form().bindFromRequest().get("plan"));
}
```

Comment: I tried the Route's argument way. However, it will open /service/register? instead of /service/register?plan=free. I checked the generated form html source, it has correct value (action="/service/register?plan=free").

Comment: I tried all possibilities before answering, `controllers.WebRegister.register(plan: String?="")` -> `/service/register?plan=free` works as expected, try to describe better, what's wrong.

Comment: This is the result html generate from me. When click, it goes to http://xxx/service/register?                                                  <form action="/service/register?plan=baron" method="GET">
<div class="form-actions plan-form peer-btn-center peer-m-v-t">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Sign Up"></div>
</form>